# Update JSON file without destroying JSON format

Tags: json, powershell, swagger

I'm trying to update a Swagger JSON document in Powershell.  I need to add a couple of properties and values if they do not already exist on the object.

The code for doing this is pretty simple:

```
$swaggerDoc = (Get-Content $filePath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)

$swaggerDoc | Add-Member -Name host -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "swagger.io" -Force
$swaggerDoc | Add-Member -Name schemes -MemberType NoteProperty -Value @("https") -Force

$swaggerDoc | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath
```

The problem I have is that the JSON gets completely destroyed when I save it back to the file:  For example

```
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "Links"
    ],
    "operationId": "Links_GetAll",
    "parameters": [],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Returns all the available links in the system",
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/AdministrativeLink"
          }
        },
        "x-nullable": true
      }
    }
  }
```

becomes

```
"get":  "@{tags=System.Object[]; operationId=Links_GetAll; parameters=System.Object[]; responses=}",
```

I haven't seen any other examples on how to do this in Powershell, is there some syntax or parameter I am missing in order to retain the original format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `ConvertTo-Json`, use `-Depth` to retain proper format of the `JSON`.

For Example:

```
$swaggerDoc | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Set-Content $filePath
```

I also had to add brackets around your JSON to make it valid JSON readable by powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are cutting and pasting then make sure you remove formatting. For example if you are using a Mac, paste with "Command + Shift + V", this will remove formatting when cutting and pasting.  Also never use "TABS" while inside of a JSON file, only "ENTER" and Spaces

Comment: You didn't list anything about your environment, so I took my best guess.

Comment: This JSON file is generated from a tool, and includes only spaces and line breaks.